# Is there any in-built swift function that can give me the processor temperature value?

Tags: swift, macos

I want to get the `temperature of the processor` for my mac using swift I know there are a bunch of github libraries that do that, but I want to know if there are any swift foundation libraries or functions that display the temperature.
I was able to find this function called `NSProcessInfoThermalState` it helps to know the state of the processor with respect to temperature like if the temperature is in normal state or in critical state while that's good I want the raw value of the processor temperature.

Comment: How do the github libraries get the temperature?

Comment: it's in c. not swift

Comment: Are the C functions available in Swift?

Comment: swift does allw for inclusion of direct c code so it should work, but i just wanted to know if there was anything purely swift based like maybe something from IOKit that displays temperature